# Inline functions in a C file and output a C file

Tags: c, compiler

I have a C file with functions and calls. I'm searching for a way to inline all calls. The output has to be a C file with only one function implementation.

There are very few extern functions which should not be inlined (like `scanf` or functions marked with `extern`). It would be ok if I had to list these functions manually.

**Impractical Solutions**

- Do the inlining by hand
  The files are too big. One file has 2'757 functions and 1'500'000 lines of code.
- A self-written script doing plain text processing.
  The C standard can be quite complicated sometimes. I wouldn't trust such a script to get everything right.
- Decompiling after compiling with inlining.
  Even with the `inline` keyword the compiler decides what to inline. There is no guarantee that all functions will be inlined. The output could be very messy.

I tagged this question as [compiler](/questions/tagged/compiler) because I thought I had seen a compiler option for `gcc` or `clang` that did exactly what I wanted. But I cannot find said option anymore. I'm not even sure such an option did exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The static analysis tool [Frama-C](https://frama-c.com/) also has some preprocessing capabilities. From Frama-C's [manual](http://frama-c.com/download/frama-c-user-manual.pdf#page=32):

> `-inline-calls <f1,...,fn>`
>            inlines calls to functions `f1,...,fn`. [...]

I used the following command to inline functions.

```
frama-c -inline-calls ... -print -ocode output.c iutput.c
```

To list the functions to be inlined I wrote a small text processing script. First GNU `indent` is applied to the program, such that all function definitions are in some sort of normal form. Then the function names are extracted using `grep -Po`.

Frama-C does inlining very well. However, the inlined functions are still left in the program, even though they are neither called nor needed anymore. To remove all functions but `main` I wrote another text processing script.

Since Frama-C's preprocessing is only for its own purpose, things from stdio got a bit mangled. `printf` and `scanf` were renamed to functions like `printf_va_34` and `scanf_va_1`. I used the following `sed` command to undo the renaming:

```
sed -Ei 's/(printf|scanf)_va_[0-9]*/\1/;s/__fc_(stdout|stderr)/\1/' inlined.c
```

The `sed` command is unsafe. For instance if `printf_va_123` was not a function call but a substring of a variable name or string literal it would still be renamed.

Finally I used `gcc -fsyntax-only -w inlined.c` to check that all the plain text processing did not mangle the program.

Comment: Welcome aboard. This is a good answer, and I hope that it will be awarded soon.

Answer (score 0):

There is ctags. The output however is not a c file, but an index file for editors like vim. Maybe you can write something that translates that index file to your needs. Hope helps!
Here link to wiki https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ctags

Comment: I don't understand how `ctags` would achieve what the OP wants